# Laravel5.3 phpunit for custom domain not working

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.3

When I try to use custom domain like this

```
<?php

abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
/**
 * The base URL to use while testing the application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

protected $prefixDomain = '';

/**
 * Creates the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
    $this->setBaseUrl();

    return $app;
}

protected function setBaseUrl()
{
    $this->baseUrl = env('APP_URL', $this->baseUrl);
    if ($this->prefixDomain) {
        $this->baseUrl = substr_replace(
            $this->prefixDomain,
            $this->baseUrl,
            strlen('https://'),
            0
        );
    }
}
```

I set the 'APP_URL' in .env file

It seems like the request uri is not right when I dump and die in Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php

```
/**
 * Find the first route matching a given request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function match(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
    $routes = $this->get($request->getMethod());
```

the output I expect here is "REQUEST_URI" => "/test" but actually

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I fixed this problem.
I should've added "http://" to APP_URL

```
// .env
APP_URL=http://domain.com
```

The code I should've seen is here

```
// Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests@654
protected function prepareUrlForRequest($uri)
{
    if (Str::startsWith($uri, '/')) {
        $uri = substr($uri, 1);
    }

    if (! Str::startsWith($uri, 'http')) {
        $uri = $this->baseUrl.'/'.$uri;
    }

    return trim($uri, '/');
}
```

Hope this will help someone like me!